# How to patch open in a static method in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, mocking

This is my method.

```
    @staticmethod
    def read_city_information(file_path):
        with open(file_path) as f:
            data_json = json.load(f)
            return data_json['result']
```

The coverage is there.But still it is taking the souce file path. Patch is not working.

```
def test_read_city_information(self):
        read_data = json.dumps({"result": [
            {
                "name": "AAAAA",
                "geofenceUUID": "4873648736846jhefjehrfjher",
                "country": "AS",
                "longitude": 6.187189579,
                "radius": 18.69953236868005,
                "latitude": 50.72419548035,
                "timezone": "Berlin"
            }]})
        mock_open1 = mock_open(read_data=read_data)
        with patch('__builtin__.open', mock_open1):
            result = PredictHQCrawlerTask.read_city_information('file_path')
            self.assertEqual(result, [{u'name': u'AAAA', u'geofenceUUID': u'234567fvefvsdvcsdcvds',
                                       u'country': u'DE', u'longitude': 6.187189579, u'radius': 18.69953236868005,
                                       u'latitude': 50.72419548035, u'timezone': u'Europe/Berlin'}])
```

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Is this on Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: @AKX Python 2.7

Comment: Fair (though you should stop using an end-of-life version of Python). Which mocking library is this? `unittest.mock` didn't appear until 3.3.

Comment: `from mock import mock_open, patch` this I am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unable to reproduce this. Python 2.7, `pip install mock`:

## so60434648.py

```
from mock import mock_open, patch
import foo
import json

def test_read_city_information():
    read_data = json.dumps({"result": "ok"})
    with patch('__builtin__.open', mock_open(read_data=read_data)):
        assert foo.Baz.read_city_information('foo') == "ok"


if __name__ == '__main__':
    test_read_city_information()
```

## foo.py

```
import json

class Baz:
    @staticmethod
    def read_city_information(file_path):
        with open(file_path) as f:
            data_json = json.load(f)
            return data_json['result']
```

Comment: Still, I am getting ```(Pdb) open
<built-in function open>``` in pdb which is builtin which means it is still taking the source path

Comment: the POC is running file for me, but in docker when I run it's not. Thanks for the answer.